# Is there a way to store fetched API data in a global variable?

Tags: javascript, module, async-await, promise

I want to fetch data from an API and store that into a variable, and export that variable to other modules for reusability.
However, I can't seem to figure out how to reuse the data..

```
// getData.js
let data;
async function getData(){
  let fetchedData = await fetch('someURL').then(value => value.json());
  data = fetchedData;
}
export { data };

// otherModule.js
import { data } from './getData.js';
console.log(data);
```

If I do this, I know that `data` will not actually wait for the promise to resolve/reject and print out empty.
So, is there a way to store the fetched data in a variable that can be exported to other modules?

Comment: have you tried this?

Comment: Probably not. You are also mixing async/await and promise chaining. Choose one of the methods to wait for the promise to resolve.

Comment: Export the promise, not a binding to a variable that might be filled at an unknown time.

Answer (score 0):

```
// getData.js
async function getData(){
  const response = await fetch('someURL');
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

export { getData };

// otherModule.js
import { getData } from './getData.js';

getData().then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: This will not cache the response between modules, you'll fetch it over and over for every module in which it is imported and used.

Comment: True. But that was not a requirement from the question. If you need caching then add some caching to it.

Comment: I think that `However, I can't seem to figure out how to reuse the data..` sounds like (even if not stated directly) caching is kind of a requirement.

Comment: Can either memoize the call or use some other way of storing the value. Depending on where this code is executing, react, angular, plain js, vue, node etc. But that context was not in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I am new to stack overflow and coding in general. I was implying some sort of caching so that I don't call the api over and over again (to save execution time and to prevent going over free api call limits/day). btw, I'm just using plain js.

Comment: Could give memoization a try. [This](https://dev.to/jadzeino/how-to-cache-your-javascript-functions-meet-the-memoization-technique-2i2l) might be a good read.

Comment: Sorry @Mellet, but memoization would still work only on the per-component basis, so if you wanted to use that data function in a few components, you'd still call the API that many times. Browser's request caching could help, but AFAIK server would still be pinged to check if data did not change.

Comment: Small [contrived example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-booth-6pkj9?file=/src/App.js) of two components in react calling the same function to fetch data from an external API and caching the value for all calls except the first.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for

```
// getData.js
export const dataPromise = fetch('someURL').then(value => value.json());
```

```
// otherModule.js
import { dataPromise } from './getData.js';
dataPromise.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```